# Undefined method error in ReflectionClass but method exists

Tags: php, reflection

I am currently using `phpunit` for some unit testing. Due to the presence of some protected methods, I had to use a `Reflection Class` to change the visibility of these methods to `public`.

The initial methods were called successfully but somehow it gets stuck at a specific method:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ReflectionClass::create_schema()in
/vagrant/fuelphp/fuel/app/tests/model/repository/jobpost.php on line 54
```

However, dumping the method via `get_method()` with `var_dump` proves that it exists in the class instance:

```
class ReflectionMethod#2317 (2) {
  public $name =>
  string(13) 'create_schema'
  public $class =>
  string(34) 'Model_Repository_Feed'
}
```

Then the real confusing bit, I decided to use `hasMethod()` to see if the method exists:

```
 52     echo "If this says 1, class exists: ".$this->_target->hasMethod('create_schema');
 53     try {
 54         $this->_target->create_schema();
 55     }
```

The result when running says, "yes it exists.... but it doesn't":

```
If this says 1, class exists: 1
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ReflectionClass::create_schema() in /vagrant/fuelphp/fuel/app/tests/model/repository/jobpost.php on line 54
```

To clarify this method is public and is inherited from an `abstract` parent class:

```
public function create_schema() {
    $this->create_schema_exec(self::$_real_schema_name);
  }
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: is the method dynamic, it may exist in the class instance, but is it in the actual class.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php can be used on the instance loaded at runtime ( I doubt this is the case ) such would be like __call(), but just a thought because of the abstract inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is inherited from its parent class, and the last block of code is from the parent class itself. Just used `getParentClass()` and it shows the right parent class

Comment: Right but it might be a scoping issue with abstract parents, the nice thing is that reflectionObject extends reflectionClass so you don't lose any functionality by trying it.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out

Comment: Sure, I used reflectionObject in my personal debugger I wrote just yesterday.

Comment: Tried `ReflectionObject` and the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the object of the class that holds the method not the reflection object.

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($className);
$object = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
$object->methodName();
```